# Correct version of droidninja for correct example.

Tags: android

I am trying to implement file picker using droid ninja but it seems the version of droidninja doesn't have exact same functions I am using following an example. Can anyone suggest me correct version of droidninja with correct example.Both should be compatible. I am using Android studio 2.3.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of this library is 2.0.3.

Just add your app's gradle file to this:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.droidninja:filepicker:2.0.3'
}
```

[This Link](https://github.com/DroidNinja/Android-FilePicker) clearly shows the necessary instructions.